Error converting an array to object in PHP
I am trying to convert an arary to object but I am getting this error message.

Message: 'Creation of dynamic property App\Models\User::$name is deprecated'

This is where the value name is used.
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

I have insantiate a standard class as a variable, and loop through your array while re-assigning the values
public function __construct($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    };
}

Why this is happening?
Is this should to turn 'name' => 'Dimitris to $user->name = 'Dimitris'?

The class definition needs to have public $name; to declare the property. You shouldn't create undeclared properties in the constructor that way.

FYI you can simply cast an associative array to stdclass if you don't need any extra functionality... $obj = (object) $arr; https://3v4l.org/810jW
